# I can't get JSONObject in post call - getting 415

Tags: java, json, rest, post

```
@POST
@Path("/sessions")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response createSession(JSONObject jsonObject){

    if (jsonObject.get("subjectId").equals("amadmin")){
        jsonObject.put("username", jsonObject.get("subjectId"));
        jsonObject.put("password", jsonObject.get("authInfo"));
    }
    else{
        jsonObject.put("username", jsonObject.get("subjectId"));
        jsonObject.put("password", jsonObject.get("authInfo"));
        jsonObject.put("uri", "realm=" + jsonObject.get("realm"));
    }

    String openAmUrl = String.format("http://%s%s/identity/json/authenticate", 
            openAmIp, openAmWarName);

    URI uri = null;
    try {
        uri = new URI(openAmUrl);
    } 
    catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception " + e);
    }
    return Response.seeOther(uri).build();
}
```

I'm trying to call a post call with JSON string like:
`{"subjectId":"me", "authInfo":"password"}`
and I'm always getting `HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type`.
I understand that if my method is receiving JSONObject then the string in the post is getting converted to JSONObject automatically, but still getting the 415 error, although Im using headers as:
Content-Type : application/json
Accept : application/json

can you please help?

Comment: Can you also post your client code which you use to call the service?

Comment: don't have client code, I use fire fox 'HTTP resource test'

Comment: Alright, post a screenshot of the same if possible.

Comment: http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/8541/httpresourcetest.jpg

Comment: I wanted to have a look at the Headers tab as well. Please post what headers you've used with the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it was simple, here is the new code:

```
POST
@Path("/sessions")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response createSession(String body){

    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(body);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        LOGGER.error("This is not a valid JSON " + e);
        return Response.status(400).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Consumes annotation is used to filter what is acceptable for the respective method, so it filters out requests that don't have Content-Type: application/json in a HTTP header.

You need to add the Header in the request

```
Content-Type: application/json
```